# Zero timeout on WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage leads to class cast exception

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

According to documentation infinite wait for message read from `JMS` queue is achieved specifying `"timeout: 0"`. Using non-zero values call to `WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage` works ok, for zero timeout function returns immediately and I can find log entry:

```
com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext E FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure jms_topic/JMSConsumerFWLSE0100E: parameters:{ "arr": [ { "destination": "myqueue", "singleMessage": true, "timeout": 0.0 }]} java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null
```

For positive value like `"timeout: 1000"` logged params are correct, also "timeout: 1000". For "timeout: 0" logged value is floating point as `"timeout: 0.0"` unexpected on Java side.

I see not way to force integral zero as literal, I tried `"timeout: 0x0"` or `"timeout: parseInt(0)"` but the problem seems to be in `JS-Java` translation. It is a pity such basic boundary condition is not tested before release.

Comment: Just for kicks, try using a timeout of -1. I've seen other IBM documentation have 0 and -1 mixed up no timeout.

Comment: It has different meaning: 0 for infinite wait, <0 for no-wait

Comment: Well if you haven't tried it and are still having problems, I'd still say just try it. To me, a timeout of 0 would mean no-wait. Thus, a negative value would mean inifinite by default. It could still be a bug the Jeremy mentioned in his answer, but if nothing else, giving this a try will help validate that idea and give you more leverage with IBM support if you choose to open a PMR.

Comment: Also if you don't mind, could you link the documentation you're referring to in your first statement? I'd like to just poke around there myself to see if there is something else to consider.

Comment: Nick, I actually tried and it is consistent with documentation - for negative value it simply tries to fetch message from queue or returns with no message immediatelly. I want to wait for message until it arrives blocking caller, thus using 0. Now the only option is to mimic waiting by large enough wait time made in a loop.
(PS. I prefer to write on well indexed forum than opening PMR as it is easier to google receipts)

Comment: Documentation for "readSingleJMSMessage" [is here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_readsinglejmsmessage.html?resultof=%22%6a%6d%73%22%20%22%6a%6d%22%20)

Comment: I understand about using SO over IBM support. A PMR is typically a last resort if there is nothing else I can do to solve my problem. One more question though: Are you using quotes in your code like they are used in your question? For example you wrote "timeout: 0.0" instead of "timeout":"0" or "timeout":0

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an unfortunate bug with no currently known workaround. A defect will be opened to fix the issue. We will continue to look for a possible workaround for current versions.

Comment: Situation is even worse. Class cast occurs also if timeout is not literal but evaluated expression (nature of JS where all numbers are floating points strikes back). Example:

    function getMessage(queue, waitSecs) {
        var result = WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage({
            destination : queue,
            timeout : 1000 * waitSecs
        });
     ...
    }